# Extension's script does not wait for whole page to load before running

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've recently started working on a chrome extension which has to wait for a YouTube page to load before adding a button at a certain place in the already existing code.

I've used `getElementById()` to get the element, but most of the time my page doesn't have time to fully load that the script already finished.

I've checked many topics regarding this issue and stumbled across `window.addEventListener('load', submitAction);` which doesn't actually waits for the **whole page** to load, or at least it doesn't look like it. When I try to print the output of the `getElementById()`'s output, the result is `null`.

I've been trying to use other kind of event listeners, using it on document and not on window, trying to wait for  `DOMContentLoaded` as it looks like it's also waiting for the document to fully load but nothing actually **waits** for the whole page to load.

The most optimal thing I would like to do would be that the page loads, when the element I am looking for loads, I simply grab it, create a button, append it and it seamlessly appears in the page without any latency.

Am I doing something wrong here?*

Here's a sample of my code :

manifest.json :

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/c/*"],
        "js": ["content-script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_idle"
      }
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    }
}
```

background.js :

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    window.onload = function() {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "content-script.js"
      });
    }
  }
})
```

content-script.js :

```
window.addEventListener('load', submitAction);

function submitAction()
{
  var youtubeName = document.getElementById("channel-name")

  console.log("========================")
  console.log(youtubeName)
  console.log("========================")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching your code to the `document-idle`, which is the *latest* `run-at` value, will fire immediately after [window.load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event fires:

> The browser chooses a time to inject scripts between "document_end" and immediately after the window.onload event fires

[source](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/)

If the DOM gets hydrated (or mutated) with elements post load, like what seemingly happens on Youtube, then the element will not exist at the time of that event firing.

I would suggest using a different method, like a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), rather than a traditional event listener.

**Example:**

```js
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.target.id === "channel-name") {
            console.log("Element found:", document.getElementById("channel-name"));
            // disconnect the observer
            observer.disconnect();
            // element exists, run your code below
        }
    }
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true });
```

The snippet above watches the dom for mutations and when a mutation occurs that has a target with the `id` of `channel-name`, it executes code. In the example above, I disconnect the observer (which you may or may not want to do) and then I log the element.

Comment: So, mutations are basically what are added after the page fully loaded? Like some kind of extra content on top of a template? or at least I get it like this, and after these mutations which occured, and it checks if they have the name of ```channel-name```, it runs my code? I also added a return statement after disconnecting the observer and running my code as it would otherwise run it like 50 times. I don't 100% understand everything and how it keeps looking for those mutations etc... but I get the general idea and it works like I wanted it now. thanks!

Comment: @pironc glad it worked out for you. A mutation observer doesn't have to be set up after the page fully loaded, but considering the nature of the observer, it will continue to observe *after page load*, anytime a DOM mutation occurs if the mutation is adheres to [the options you set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe).

Comment: Oh so I could use it, or even should use it for any lookout of any classes/id/... I'm trying to get in a page as it would "never fail" and return null but keep looking until found? Or would this be a bad practice, i.e. if it's memory intensive (maybe not for such small projects I guess) and if another way would be more efficient in some cases?

Comment: @pironc I use mutation observers often and I think it depends on the program as a whole to determine the cost of use. I assume they are less performant than event listeners, but that doesn't mean they will result in poor performance. Another method could be using a `setInterval` function or a recursive `setTimeout`. - [Here's an example using `setInterval`](https://jsfiddle.net/cm3o059n/). It checks the DOM every 250ms and when the element is found, it clear the interval func and executes code. Personally, I prefer event driven methods (like mutation observers), but it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't help, but try adding "defer" to your script tags:

```
<script defer src="script_file_name.js"></script>
```

defer makes your .js files to wait for the whole HTML to finish parsing.

Comment: I'm not sure on where to add this, as I don't have any HTML files but only the files specified in the post and I'm not either experiences a lot in this domain. Isn't the <script> tag included in HTML to run script in some parts of it?

Comment: Oh you're right, it was my bad. Skipped the fact that you're talking about a browser extension